# Why blender throws an exception when saving a copy of image?

Tags: python

I'm developing blender exporter for CryEngine - [CryBlend](https://github.com/travnick/CryBlend).

I need to convert an image to tiff and then pass it to cryengine resource compiled. The thing is it works while saving image with blender python console:

```
tiffImage= bpy.data.images[1].copy()
tiffImage.filepath_raw = 'new_path.tif'
tiffImage.file_format = 'TIFF'
tiffImage.save()
```

but the same code placed in plugin throws an exception at save()

"RuntimeError: Error: Image "my image" does not have any image data."

What's more, while debugging that code with pydev (in plugin) then it works as expected.
I'm totally puzzled with it.

[here is the complete code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fastio123a3z3bo/CryBlendTest.7z). export.py:1196

```
def __export_library_images(self, parent_element):
    library_images = self.__doc.createElement("library_images")
    parent_element.appendChild(library_images)

    for image in self.__get_texture_images_for_selected_objects():
        tiffFilePath = self.__convert_to_tiff_and_save(image)
        image_path = get_relative_path(tiffFilePath)

        image_element = self.__doc.createElement("image")
        image_element.setAttribute("id", "%s" % image.name)
        image_element.setAttribute("name", "%s" % image.name)
        init_from = self.__doc.createElement("init_from")
        path_node = self.__doc.createTextNode("%s" % image_path)
        init_from.appendChild(path_node)
        image_element.appendChild(init_from)
        library_images.appendChild(image_element)

def __convert_to_tiff_and_save(self, image):
    if image.file_format is not 'TIFF':
        tiffFilePath = os.path.splitext(image.filepath)[0] + ".tif"
        cbPrint(tiffFilePath, 'debug')

        if self.__config.run_rc_and_do_materials:
            try:
                tiffImage = image.copy()
                tiffImage.filepath_raw = tiffFilePath
                tiffImage.file_format = 'TIFF'
                tiffImage.save()
            finally:
                # remove tmp image from blend file database
                bpy.data.images.remove(tiffImage)
    else:
        tiffFilePath = image.filepath

    return tiffFilePath
```

Comment: There are some strange things here: You shouldn't be getting an exception since you're in a `try` block when this happens, and you're catching *all*  exceptions (bad boy, you!). Also (unrelated), you should never use `if image.file_format is not 'TIFF':` This needs to be `if image.file_format != TIFF':`. Furthermore, your `__convert_to_tiff_etc.()` doesn't return anything, but your other method seems to think it does...

Comment: __convert_to_tiff_etc.() returns, but that code was not pasted: fixed. I'm catching all exceptions because I want to delete that temporary image from blender database no matter what.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `save_render()` to save to whatever format you want, no need to duplicate an image datablock first.

In my experience, `save_render()` is the only reliable way to export from one format to another. I tried the `.filepath_raw / .file_format` way as well, but it turned out to not actually write the data in the expected format (it used the source format with target format's extension).

Note that `save_render()` does **not** render anything, it is called ...`_render` because it uses the render settings of the current scene.

```
import bpy

img = bpy.data.images[0] # pick an image datablock
filepath = r"C:\tmp\_exported_image.tif" # specify outout filepath here

# Store current render settings
settings = bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings
format = settings.file_format
mode = settings.color_mode
depth = settings.color_depth

# Change render settings to our target format
settings.file_format = 'TIFF'
settings.color_mode = 'RGBA'
settings.color_depth = '8'

# Save image to TIF, this does NOT render anything!
# It only means that the save command will use the current scene's render settings.
img.save_render(filepath)

# Restore previous render settings
settings.file_format = format
settings.color_mode = mode
settings.color_depth = depth
```